# Hiding sql in php

Tags: php, sql

How can you hide sql in php, (create common sql commands or functions in php), so you don't have sql statement in your php code? I don't want to use an ORM or OOP.

PunBB does something like this:

```
$query = array(
    'SELECT'    => 'f.id AS fid, f.forum_name, f.moderators, f.redirect_url, fp.post_replies, fp.post_topics, t.id AS tid, t.subject, t.first_post_id, t.closed, p.poster, p.poster_id, p.message, p.hide_smilies, p.posted',
    'FROM'      => 'posts AS p',
    'JOINS'     => array(
        array(
            'INNER JOIN'    => 'topics AS t',
            'ON'            => 't.id=p.topic_id'
        ),
        array(
            'INNER JOIN'    => 'forums AS f',
            'ON'            => 'f.id=t.forum_id'
        ),
        array(
            'LEFT JOIN'     => 'forum_perms AS fp',
            'ON'            => '(fp.forum_id=f.id AND fp.group_id='.$forum_user['g_id'].')'
        )
    ),
    'WHERE'     => '(fp.read_forum IS NULL OR fp.read_forum=1) AND p.id='.$id
);
```

Anyone know how this is implemented?

Comment: Why?  You want to deliberately make your code **less** readable and maintainable?  Care you explain why?

Comment: I can understand why he would want to do this; This makes it easier to dynamically generate a Query, as you can simply add/overwrite commands/clauses with `$query['WHERE'] = 'parameters'` and remove them with `unset($query['WHERE']);`. This would be much more difficult, if you had to parse the Query-String everytime you want to do something with it.

Comment: If someone has access to your source code, are you really worried about concealing the fact that you're using SQL?

Comment: @andre: I am under the assumption that what you're saying is not what (s)he's asking for due to the word *hiding* in the title.  If that's what (s)he's asking, then fair enough.  But with the vagueness of the question, it's hard to tell for sure...

Comment: lol, well, if you would want to hide it, you could just base64-encode it and then do something like `mysql_query ( base64_decode ( 'base64-encoded-query' ) );`, but that would be really, really strange. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a MySQL-Query based on your Array with the following Function:

```
function create_query ($array) {

    $query = '';        

    foreach ( $array as $command => $parameters ) {
        $query .= " $command ";
        if ( is_array ( $parameters ) )
            $query .= " ( " . create_query ( $parameters ) . " ) "; // Hello recursion
        else
            $query .= "$parameters ";
    }

    return $query;

}
```

This function assumes, that the keys of the array are **always** MySQL-Commands and the values are parameters, if they are strings, or more commands, if they are arrays.